# In Objective-C, why doesn't arrayWithObjects add a nil to the end of list automatically?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does NSArray arrayWithObjects require a terminating nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309535/why-does-nsarray-arraywithobjects-require-a-terminating-nil)

It is said that we need to always use a `nil` as the last item for `arrayWithObjects`:

```
NSArray *wordList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"hello", @"world", nil];
```

Why can't `arrayWithObjects` not require the `nil` and just add the `nil` for us.  Some forum said that's because the `nil` act as a sentinel for other methods... but isn't that an implementation issue that shouldn't concern the user of the class?

For example, if other languages require

```
 list = [1 ,2, nil]    # Ruby
```

to build an array, it can be somewhat weird.

Comment: Because it doesn't know how.  It's a standard variable-length parm list, and there must be some sort of count or end marker for the length to be known.

Comment: It can be done with a macro, but other than that, what @HotLicks said is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the automatic nil insertion would require some language or compiler extension.

In the case of the variadic list, the terminator's required for the implementation to know when to stop reading.

Fortunately, your compiler supports sentinel attributes, so this should not be a problem if you turn up and pay attention to your compiler warnings.

Comment: Such a compiler extension is [coming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693647/is-there-some-literal-dictionary-or-array-syntax-in-objective-c)!  Hallelujah!

Comment: there is no way that `arrayWithObjects` adds the `hello` and the `world`, and then adds the `nil`?

Comment: @動靜能量: The `nil` isn't part of the array; it's used to find the end of the list of arguments. The method itself can't know how many arguments it got.

Comment: @IuliusCæsar yes - good news, indeed :)

Comment: @動靜能量 well, you could create some convenience methods/functions, if that's actually useful for your case (approximately as complex to write, but enhanced checking would be available).