# What is the point of nil when init NSArray?

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to objective-C. I'm just read some of article, and I saw that when init Array or Set, the writer do something like:
`NSArray *list=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Andy",@"Erik",@"Aaron",nil];` 
I'm try to not use nil and nothing change, so, what is the point of **nil** when init an array or a set?

Comment: This should answer your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309535/why-does-nsarray-arraywithobjects-require-a-terminating-nil

Comment: thanks, @Chaikitty, I didn't found that one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how the 'method' 'knows' that you've given it the last item
in the list so it can know for sure when it reaches the end of the
arguments for the method.

```
NSArray *listdemo = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Andy",@"Erik",@"Aaron",nil];
```

The method is iterating
through the list until it finds nil. If it doesn't, it runs off the
end and Bad Things happen.